# Involvement of central statistics bureau with national open data portal

Tags: government, best-practice, data-portal, census

Although this is a very subjective question as each national government has quite a different setup. However, in general, are there any patterns or working models involving statistics bureaus having a more involved role in either hosting, curating, managing, evangelizing, policy making, etc for the country open data portal?

Are there examples where the national open data portal was solely or jointly serviced by national statistics bureaus?

What might be the potential good practices in establishing roles and responsibilities between statistics bureaus, national information and ID centers, eGovernment programs, other ministries of significance etc?

Answer (score 1):

I have a CSV dataset you should find useful. It contains primary government website URLs for all countries in the world. The third field is to the country's statistical division.

http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#govweb

Comment: Thanks Andrew, very helpful sheet indeed. However, im afraid it's not exactly what I am looking for. My question is more from practice perspective of various governments.